# Debugging IDAPython Scripts outside of IDAPro

Tags: python, debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

I'm kinda new to scripting for IDA - nevertheless, I've written a complex script I need to debug, as it is not working properly.

It is composed of a few different files containing a few different classes.
Writing line-by-line in the commandline is not effective for obvious reasons.
Running a whole script from the File doesn't allow debugging.

**Is there a way of using the idc, idautils, idaapi not from within IDA?**

I've written the script on PyDev for Eclipse, I'm hoping for a way to run the scripts from within it.

A similar question is, **can the api classes I have mentioned work on idb files without IDA having them loaded?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now I may be wrong for I haven't written any IDA script for long time. But as far as I remember the answer to your first question is no. There is the part that loads the IDA script and prepare the whole environment so you could re implement it and create your own environment, however I would not recommend that.

What I can tell you is to consider running your script from command line if automation is what you are aiming for. IDA python (as well as any other IDA plugin) have a good support for running scripts from command line. For performance you can also run the TUI version of IDA.

There is also a hack for that enables you to launch a new python interpreter in the middle of the IDA script. It is useful for debugging a current state yet you will still need to edit the python file every time to launch the interpreter.
Here is the hack:

```
import code
all = globals()
all.update(locals())
code.interact(local = all)
```

Anyway - logs are good and debug prints are OK.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have been trying to use the cmdline, but it's painful beacuse the script is long and comprised of several modules (residing in different files). I will consider usin the TUI version of IDA. Where can I look for info about the hack you've mentioned?

Comment: The hack was added to the answer.

If the script is long that's another reason you should consider using the TUI.

Answer (score 0):

We've just got a notice from one of our users that the latest version of WingIDE supports debugging of IDAPython scripts. I think there are a couple of other programs using the same approach (import a module to do RPC debugging) that might work.